# Generating "unique" matricies

Tags: c++, math, matrix

This may be more of a math question than a programming question but since I am specifically working in c++ I figured maybe there was a library or something I didn't know about.
Anyway I'm working on a game where I'm generating some X by X arrays of booleans and randomly assigning Y of them to be true. Think tetris block kind of stuff. What I need to know is if there's a clever way to generate "unique" arrays without having to rotate the array 4 times and compare each time. To use tetris as an example again. an "L" piece is an "L" piece no matter how it's rotated, but a "J" piece would be a different unique piece. As a side question, is there a way to determine the maximum number of unique possible configurations for an X by X array with Y filled in elements?

Answer (score 1):

You could sum `(x-X/2)^2 + (y-X/2)^2` for each (x,y) true grid element. This effectively gives the squared distances from the centre of your grid to each "true" cell. Two grids that are the same when rotated share the property that their "true" cells are all the same distances from the centre, so this sum will also be the same. If the grids all have unique sums of squares, they are unique under rotation.

Note that although unique sums guarantees no rotational duplicates, the converse isn't true; two non-matching grids can have the same sum of squares.

If your grids are quite small and you are struggling to maximize the number of different patterns, you'll probably want to test those with equal sums. Otherwise, if your generator spits out a grid with a sum of squares that matches a previously created grid, reject it.

Comment: "If the grids..." Or "if and only if the grids..."

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica exactly. So weed out the duplicates. If the grids are large enough to have to algorithmically generate them, you should have plenty of options remaining.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually pretty cool, I'll try this but I also got a bit of inspiration yesterday. Because I can represent the grids as filled or empty blocks, I can convert it into binary, and then in turn into a decimal. Then for each new generated piece, you only need to compare the current orientation with all previous stored integers, and then if it's good, convert the new piece, rotate 3 times and store each binary/int representation.

Comment: @LilyStorm I thought about that too, but wasn't sure how big the grids were. It should work up to 8 x 8. I was also thinking whether some numerical trick might find the rotated integers more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is make a basic form: somehow uniquely decide which orientation among the 4 possible ones is the basic one and then compare them via the basic forms only.

How to decide which form is the basic one? It doesn't really matter as long as it is consistent. Say, pick the highest one according to lexicographical comparison.

Edit:
About the number of unique shapes: roughly speaking it is binomial number `(n^2 over k)/4` - only that it doesn't take into account symetrical shapes that are preserved by 180° rotation, though there are only a few such shapes in comparison (at least for large n,k).

Side note: you should also consider the case of shapes that differ by shift only.